# What nomenclature do names like fumarate and malate derive from?

Tags: nomenclature

When reviewing the citric acid cycle, I find names like glutarate and succinate to be helpful in thinking about the structure of the molecules because I was taught about the sequential [dicarboxylic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dicarboxylic_acid) naming scheme: oxalic (2 carbon), malonic (3C), succinic (4C), glutaric (5C) etc.

But I often struggle with **fumarate** and **malate** because I have not learned the numbering or nomenclature system that these names are derived from. Can someone point me in the right direction so that I can learn the background behind these names?

Knowing that will be helpful to my recall of the molecular **structure**. Then I can stop memorizing and start understanding.

Comment: As per the OED, the etymology of  maleic is related to that of malate. Loss of water from the latter gives the cis-form of the former.

Comment: malic, maleic, and malonic acids have all the same origin : malus = apple in latin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you will have to memorize the structures and the names because there is no chemical structure hidden in those names.

From Elsevier's Dictionary of Chemoetymology

> fumaric acid $\ce{C4H4O4}$, derived from the genus name Fumaria (fumitory), from fumus (Latin:
> smoke)

Fumaria plant
[image]

> malic acid $\ce{C4H6O5}$, derived from malum (Latin: apple)

The same goes for all other common names like oxalic acid, acetic acid etc.

Comment: *"Dictionary of Chemoetymology"* Price is a bit steep, but would you otherwise recommend it?

Comment: My favorite source of historical word origins is the unabridged version of the Oxford English Dictionary. It is also subscription based. OED will most likely have 99% of the words contained in *Chemoetymology*.

Comment: How is *Chemoetymology* stuctured? Just A-Z?

Comment: Yes, A-Z just like a dictionary. If you want more "stories" and the names which are *not* present in OED is Alex Nikon's "Organic Chemistry- The Name Game" is worth it.

Comment: Also *Chemoetymology" has no pictures. I just added Fumaria from the web.

Comment: Yea, I'd want a good enlightening read, not a dictionary. Unfortunately, that one is also from Elsevier and therefore equally overpriced, for a Christmas or graduation present. ;-)

Comment: Formic comes from the dry distillation of ants, this makes me wonder :))